# Why is onCreate() in Activity protected?

Tags: android, android-activity

Why is the onCreate() in Activity protected?

or I should ask: why does it work?

Protected method can only be called in the inside of the class itself or it's descendants. So Android system can't call it like "act.onCreate()". So... how can it be called?

BTW, why is onClick() in OnClickListener is public? What's the difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that protected methods can also be called from other classes *within the same package*.  `Activity` is in the `android.app` package, so any class in `android.app` (such as `android.app.Instrumentation`) can call `onCreate` on an activity directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's useful to have public onClick methods because you can "force" certain buttons to be clicked programmatically. A common example of this is causing the same to code to execute when the user presses the enter key, or pressed the Submit button.

I don't think Android calls Activity.onCreate directly. Note that Activity inherits from Context (which [does have a public constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#Context%28%29)). It is my understanding that the constructor triggers some events to occur, and the onCreate/Pause/Resume/Destroy methods are called internally to the class at the appropriate time.

For example, when you create an activity, the view XML file has to be parsed and inflated. This happens automatically, so there's something happening behind the scenes that you don't directly control.

Comment: Inflating a XML happens automatically? So that what's setContentView()?

Comment: I'm not sure if setContentView actually inflates the XML file. The docs don't say either way.

Comment: From the Activity.setContentView() docs..."Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity."

Comment: @Squonk: I seem to remember seeing a Google I/O conference talk where they said that layout inflation may not happen exactly when you think it will due to the way Android optimizes the process. So yes, after calling setContentView(), the layout will be inflated. But I don't think it's guaranteed that the layout will be inflated in that call.

Answer (score 9):

the **onCeate()** is protected so to avoid calling of it from the activity object.

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
activity.onCreate(args);  // which doesn't make sense because activity is not yet created
```

Since this method is only called when the activity gets created, calling it yourself will most probably give you a **nullpointerException** because the activity is not yet created.

Answer (score 3):

onCreate is not public because you don't want a random class in a totally different package creating an activity.

If I design an Activity class in a com.abccompany.activity package, and one of my co-workers designs a JSON data parsing class in a com.abccompany.jsonparser package, I don't want him creating my activity and displaying his JSON data whenever he wants.

onCreate is not private because you do want to subclass an Activity and then use the super Activity onCreate method for the subclass.

Actually every Activity you design extends android.app.Activity, so if onCreate was private in that super class, then you wouldn't be able to call onCreate at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you care wether the onCreate is protected? Is protected because logically it should not be accessed by other class different from Activities. How does Android launch the Activity? There are a lot of ways of doing that, specially if you're the one who designed the framework, the solution could be that is being invoked on the constructor (a possibility) o by other mechanisms like reflection with the appropriate privileges, etc.

The onClick is public because it could be set or handled by external classes that not necessary are your Activity. By this I mean that class A could be able to handle the onClick event of the Activity.