# Is XML file parsed automatically and inflated automatically?

Tags: android

Is this true :  that when you create an activity, the view XML file has to be parsed and inflated. This happens automatically, so there's something happening behind the scenes that you don't directly control.

Answered at ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652780/2125918 )

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setContentView` and pass to it the *resource identifier* for your `layout_file.xml` it will be parsed and the controls/views will be generated for you.

It is not true that you do not have control, you can do this process manually (i.e. generate the Views programmatically from the XML) if you like, but it is not a common situation.

You can combine both worlds by defining your core views in `layout_file.xml` and then generate dynamic views programmatically if you need to.